# Convertir sèrie de strings en uno solo

Tags: python

Tengo este trozo de código en Python

```
  import random 
  numeros=["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d"]
  listaColores=random.sample(numeros,6)
  hexColor=("#",listaColores)
  print(hexColor)
```

esto me arroja lo siguiente:

```
('#', ['d', '4', '2', 'a', 'b', '0'])
```

me gustaría que en vez de esto me saliese `#d42ab0`

*Obviamente la serie de números que siguen al # no son relevantes pues han sido seleccionados al azar con el método `random`.

Comment: Por si te puede intersar, una forma simple de obtener aleatoriamente una cadena de color aleatoria de 6 dígitos hexadecimales: `f"#{random.randint(16**6):06x}"`

Comment: @ChemaCortes Buen truco! Pero debe ser `randint(0, 16**6-1)`

Comment: Tienes razón. Ya puestos: `f"#{random.randint(0, 0xffffff):06x}"`

Answer (score 0):

La forma más fácil:

```
import random

numeros = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "a", "b", "c", "d"]
listaColores = random.sample(numeros, 6)
s = "#" + ''.join(listaColores)
print(s)
```

Hay que simplificar. En

```
hexColor=("#",listaColores)
```

estas creando una tupla con una cadena y una lista, lo que me impide usar un `join` para unir los digitos. Entonces, mejor uso directamente la lista de colores:

```
''.join(listaColores)
```

produce una cadena como `50287d`; sólo falta anteponer el "#", lo que hago por simple concatenación:

```
s = "#" + ''.join(listaColores)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @CandidMoe